# pimcore related object offset

Tags: php, object, pimcore

I am working on a `pimcore` project (`version 4.4.3`) but still pretty new to `pimcore` itself.

First I made an Object called `'Event'` in the admin panel and added a data `component -> relation ->` Object called `'speakers'.`

Now I have a `controllerAction` which needs to return these speakers, but I don't want them all at once so I wish to add a limit and offset.

The result of `$eventClass->getSpeakers()` returns an array with objects on which I don't seem to be able to put any filters.
Of course I can filter them after I retrieved all of them, but if possible I would like to filter them in my request.

So my question is, how do I filter the related objects on my `object`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that currently you can do it only using SQL. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT dest_id FROM object_relations_5 where fieldname = 'speakers' and src_id = 123 LIMIT 10;
```

Where 5 should be your class' id and 123 your object's id. You can join other tables to do more filtering, but it's getting complicated.

Commonly if you have to write custom SQL code, something is wrong with your data model. Maybe your "speaker" class should have a single href relation to "event" - this way you could get speakers listing easily with all filtering you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Listing object for that

```
$speakerId = 123;
$list = new \Pimcore\Model\Object\Event\Listing();
$list->setCondition("speakers like '%,".$speakerId.",%'");
```

But you can only filters the speakers with their IDs only. If you want to filter them with some other attributes then you have to make a join with object_relations_ClassID table.

Also have a look at the following link
https://pimcore.com/docs/4.6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Relation_Types.html#page_Filtering-for-relations-via-PHP-api